# Duplicate class MultiDex$V14.class

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, android-multidex

My Android gradle build is failing during the ProGuard phase with a duplicate class error for MultiDex$V14.class (see below). I understand what a duplicate class is and I know what MultiDex is but I still don't understand how it's a duplicate.

Questions:

1. I see one definition is in multidex.jar, of course. How can I tell where the other is defined?
2. Isn't ProGuard supposed to remove duplicate entries instead of complaining about them?
3. The "What went wrong" description at the bottom seems unrelated to the duplicate class. Is it?

-

```
    (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: can't write resource [.gitkeep] (Duplicate zip entry [DMMPlaybackBitrateSwitching-1.0.jar:.gitkeep])
...
Warning: can't write resource [.gitkeep] (Duplicate zip entry [DMMDigitalMusicLocatorServiceClient-1.0.jar:.gitkeep])
Exception while processing task 
java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/fruitman/dev/MusicAndroid-one/build/DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne/DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne-11.0/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/android-gradle/intermediates/classes-proguard/fourfireOS/debug/classes.jar] (Can't read [/Users/fruitman/dev/MusicAndroid-one/build/DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne/DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne-11.0/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/tmp/artifacts/multidex.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [multidex.jar:android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class]))
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:187)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:79)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:427)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:175)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot read [/Users/fruitman/dev/MusicAndroid-one/build/DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne/DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne-11.0/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/tmp/artifacts/multidex.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [multidex.jar:android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class])
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:176)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [multidex.jar:android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class]
    at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
    at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
    ... 12 more
:DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne:shrinkFourFireOSDebugMultiDexComponents FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne:shrinkFourFireOSDebugMultiDexComponents'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't read [/Users/fruitman/dev/MusicAndroid-one/build/DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne/DigitalMusicAndroidAppOne-11.0/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/android-gradle/intermediates/classes-proguard/fourfireOS/debug/classes.jar] (Can't process class [com/company/communication/ir/ParcelableIRServiceEndpoint.class] (Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream))

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 47.07 secs

                        BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: The "what went wrong" references `ParcelableIRServiceEndpoint`, so that would depend on what you are doing there

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes but what does that have to do with the duplicate MultiDex class? I looked at ParcelableIRServiceEndpoint. It's a very simple class located in an imported jar and doesn't include or define anything to do with MultiDex.

Comment: Not sure. I just thought that "Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream" might mean something in that class

Comment: I'm not sure either, but I believe the duplicate class is the root cause and the second error was caused by the first.

Answer (score -1):

after two days ,i find the question ,in the lib..multidex 1.0.1,,but dependencies is 1.0.0,so just kill the lib,it's work now