# Duplicate class androidx.multidex.MultiDex after migrating to Androidx

Tags: android, migration, androidx, android-multidex

I have migrated my project to androidx. After migrating I am getting the following error.

```
Duplicate class androidx.multidex.MultiDex found in modules classes.jar 
(androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1) and jetified-android-support- 
 multidex.jar (android-support-multidex.jar)
 Duplicate class androidx.multidex.MultiDex$V14 found in modules 
 classes.jar (androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1) and jetified-android- 
  support-multidex.jar (android-support-multidex.jar)
```

How to resolve this?

Found this link but has no answer,
[Duplicate class MultiDex$V14.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959409/duplicate-class-multidexv14-class)

Gradle dependencies added belwo,

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:$playServiceVersion"

// Retrofit & Rx java & Dagger
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$retrofitLoggerVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:$rxJavaAdapterVersion"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion"
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"

// Google services
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0"

// Design libraries
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

//    compile 'com.android.support:transition:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'


implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
```

}

Comment: try removing `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1` from your gradle

Comment: Removed mulidex dependency, but still same error

Comment: check if playServiceVersion and firebase-messaging veriosn is same ?

Comment: No. playServiceVersion is 16.0.0

Comment: try using same version of playservices and firebase

Comment: yes did that, kept the same version for all firebase dependencies. but still the same

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have defined constraint layout dependency 2 times

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

Comment: removed the duplicate constraint layout dependency, cleaned. Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that u are having 2 libraries having the same class name and package name. Keep the androidx version and delete the android support version.like this

```
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'
```

and do this in gradle properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="- 
Xmx4096M" \
-XX\:MaxPermSize\=256m -XX\:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError - 
Dfile.encoding\=UTF-8
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

and also add in module app

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 29
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
```

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: post your gradle

Comment: @akshay_shahane added gradle dependencies

Comment: @hasan_shaikh i also added this.can you check and try this?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by removing the jar file from libs.
Multidex jar file was present in libs folder and its dependency was also there in the gradle.

So after removing the jar file, It ran perfectly.